# How to return mock object as a null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, httppostedfilebase

as the topic says I don't know how to return a mocked object as null in my MVC Testing project. I'm new on making unit tests.

I have an action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ClubToAddVM  clubToAddVm, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (imageFile!=null)
        {
            clubToAddVm.ImageMimeType = imageFile.ContentType;
            clubToAddVm.ImageData = new byte[imageFile.ContentLength];
            imageFile.InputStream.Read(clubToAddVm.ImageData, 0, imageFile.ContentLength);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And I want in my test to pass the imageFile object as a null. Unfortunately I can't create instance of `HttpPostedFileBase` abstract class and I wanna try with something like this:

```
var mockImageFile = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
```

But then I don't know how to make it as null, because
`mockImageFile.Object` is readonly.
Any ideas?

Comment: Just set your object as null directly no need of mock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create an instance if you want to make it `null`, just do:

```
HttpPostedFileBase imageFile = null;
```

That it is an abstract class does indeed mean that you cannot create an instance of it, but it is perfectly fine to declare a variable of that type and set it to `null`.

Comment: I am very ashamed. It's obvious. I was stuck-minded. Thanks for  the help